# What is the difference between Qiyaam al-Layl and Tahajjud?

Tags: salat, tahajjud

Assalamu alaikum.

I have 3 questions relating prayer of Qiyaam al-Layl & Tahajjud.

## Difference between Qiyaam al Layl & Tahajjud?

### Do I have to niyyah?

#### Our Prophet (PBUH) prayed Qiyaam al Layl or Tahajjud most?

Comment: All these questions have answers on the site just click on the corresponding tags. As to the last one once you've found the answers of the first 2 you'll deduce that it doesn't make sense. As Tahajjud is basically qiyaam al-Layl or better is part of it.

Comment: Qiyaam al layl is like tahajjud but not tahajjud because when u don’t sleep and pray in part of night (e.g before sleep) but tahajjud is when u do ur sleep and wake up in 3rd part of night before fajr to perform it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Qiyaam al-layl means spending (part of) the night in acts of worship and is more general than Tahajjud, while Tahajjud is part of it.
2. Obviously you must have the intention to perform the action for it to be counted as an act for worship.
3. This question is invalid as as they are related not mutually exclusive.

Reference: [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/143240/)